# openl link in background tab and open modal in current tab

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, bootstrap-modal

My code:

```
//html

<?php
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$stmt =$DBConnect->query($sql);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>" class="link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=430,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">

<?php include "modal.php"; } ?>

// modal.php

<div id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="modal fade code-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code, `modal` popup in the same tab and the link `<?php echo $row['link']; ?>` open in new window.

My expected output is, the modal should open in the current tab and stay in the same tab and the link `<?php echo $row['link']; ?>` should open in background tab of the current window.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but you can't keep a modal open when the page changes. If your `link` opens in the same tab, the page will change and the modal disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new  tag that will be hidden and that contains the link that should be opened in background:

```
<a href="your_link" target="_blank" class="hidden new_tab_link"></a>
```

And in js:

```
var myModalEl = document.getElementById('myModal')
myModalEl.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // do something like $('.new_tab_link').click()
})
```